# SSH Port Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up an ssh port forwarding from my router to my linux host. I'm using the dynamic dns service from http://www.dnsexit.com. I'm using their subdomain and I have already installed the client to update the ip when it changes.

On my router, ZXHN H108N, I have set up port forwarding for ssh to a linux host. I have checked using the service at http://www.portcheckers.com/ whether the ssh port is available or not, it is available. Yet when i'm trying to ssh on my subdomain, it says

```
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XX.XX port 22: Connection refused
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the external IP from within your LAN? That won't work...

Comment: @jasonwryan I'd be very interested to know more about this. As far as I know, once you've set up port forwarding, and allowed external connections to the SSH daemon, you can use your external IP to reach it just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of  jasonwryan, The issue was that I was trying to login with the lan, so it won't work